# Azure API Management - Adding header and query parameters to APIM operation using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

How can I add headers and query parameters to an APIM operation using the Azure CLI. I know how to do this with the REST API, so I was wondering if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `headers` or `queryParameters` with these calls:

```
az apim api operation update --api-id my-api-id --operation-id my-operation-id -g my-rg -n my-apim-service-name --add request.headers name="test" type="string"

az apim api operation update --api-id my-api-id --operation-id my-operation-id -g my-rg -n my-apim-service-name --add request.queryParameters name="test" type="string"
```

where key value pairs to be used for `headers` and `queryParameters` are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apioperation/update#parametercontract)